# How to fix "This app has been blocked for your protection" error message in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac

Windows 10 UAC has been blocked my application and every time showing "This app has been blocked for your protection" error message.

I have searched online for help but none of theme helped me to fix this issue. I have applied properly even I have restarted my PC couple of times after each individual actions.

I have removed cache, refreshed registry settings also before that uninstalled the app to reinstall again using Administrator account. Unfortunately nothing worked yet.

Some of links those I have followed to solve the issue-

[How to bypass "This app has been blocked for your protection" error](https://superuser.com/questions/929945/how-to-bypass-this-app-has-been-blocked-for-your-protection-error)

https://www.wiknix.com/solved-this-app-has-been-blocked-for-your-protection/

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

Source taken from : http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/windows-10-how-fix-this-app-has-been-blocked-your-protection-error-1516240

> Step 1: Launch Start Menu, search and select Command Prompt. Then
>   right-click on it and choose Run as Administrator from the context
>   menu.
>
> Step 2: Type the following command without quotes at the Command
>   Prompt and then hit Enter:
>
> net user administrator /active:yes
>
> You should see the message saying "command completed successfully".
>
> Step 3: Launch Start Menu once again and right-click on user-account
>   title at the top-left of the screen. Then click Sign-out.
>
> Step 4: At the login screen, log into the Administrator account and
>   you will return to the Desktop of that user profile.
>
> Step 5: Locate and run the .exe file for the program which you want to
>   install.
>
> Step 6: As you have already logged into the Administrator account, the
>   Smartscreen protection will be disabled and the installation should
>   complete successfully.
>
> Step 7: After you have completed the installation, just log back into
>   your regular account after logging out of the Admin account.
>
> Step 8: Finally, disable the Administrator account that was used
>   earlier to prevent malicious access to your system files from external
>   sources like hackers and cyber-criminals.
>
> Just execute the following command (without quotes) to accomplish this
>   feat from Command Prompt: "net user administrator /active:no".

Hope that helps !!

Comment: This is **exactly** the same solution as in the second link in the question (which the OP said didn't work).

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). I've fixed the quoting in your answer.

Comment: I already tried this approach but did not work. I could not add more than 2 links also upload screenshot due to insufficient number of reputation.