# Windows Smart Screen can't be reached in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, security, microsoft-edge, microsoft-smartscreen

I keep receiving the "Windows Smart Screen can't be reached right now" prompt when Installing software. I visited the [Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/i-keep-getting-a-prompt-that-windows-smart-screen/b4eee567-635e-4265-ab49-fbb323b5467e) for support, but it only provides troubleshooting steps for connecting to the Internet.

My internet connection is working properly, so I don't know why the prompt is appearing.

Comment: Smart Screen requires the internet connection to work properly.  If there is an internet issue preventing Smart Screen running correctly you can temporarily turn it off. See [How to bypass "This app has been blocked for your protection" error](http://superuser.com/q/929945)

Comment: Ya noted that it requires an Internet Connection that's why I asked here .I have a good Internet Connection and at the time of asking here I was installing  a messenger through Edge later at which it gave this prompt.

Comment: I received this notice while trying to install an application after having  turned on  "network discovery".  I turned off "network discovery" and no longer received the notice.

Answer (score 4):

One possible cause is **if a firewall is blocking Windows Explorer** from accessing the internet.

Nothing in my applications list looked obviously related to Smart Screen, so when I had this error, I went through my firewall settings MS application by MS application. Windows Explorer is the one where it didn't work before I created an exemption allowing it to connect, and did work (or at least, didn't give this error) after.

---

(note: this is Windows 8.1, it might be different in Windows 10, but it's something to try)

Comment: How did you create the exception?  I cannot find `SmartScreen.exe` anywhere on my system, and I have numerous SmartScreenXXX folders in my system apps.  I have blocked all OUTBOUND connections unless a rule allows, similar to the default settings for INBOUND connections.  I have been able to create exceptions for `Firefox` and `Chrome` by allowing their EXE files to make outbound connections.  How did you create a rule to allow SmartScreen to make outbound connections?

Comment: @Jonathan It wasn't listed as SmartScreen, it was "Windows Explorer" that I gave the permission to - but this was 4 years ago so it might have changed. Basically look for things that look like official pieces of Windows itself. How to make the exception depends on which firewall program you are using. I don't remember which I was using, I *think* it was Glasswire and was simply ticking something in a list

Answer (score 2):

First off - check the date and time on your computer to make sure that it is accurate.

If that doesn't work then your TCP/IP or Winsock stack could be borked and will need to be rebuilt.

Open a command prompt as Administrator.

1. Type `netsh i ip r all` and press enter.
2. Type `netsh winsock reset` and press enter.

**Note:** If you have set your computer's IP address as static on your network, you will need to reapply those settings as the TCP/IP reset clears these settings.  Most people should be fine if they are using DHCP at home to connect.  I wouldn't run these on any type of work computer though, because you'll probably have to annoy your IT department to fix the IP address settings up again.

Comment: This worked for me, although it could've also been the restart that fixed it ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I had this happen on *another* computer and this fixed it, too, this time without doing a restart (and it also fixed the Office 365 Unlicensed Product issue)

Answer (score 2):

This happens when your private network is not set up. I am using wifi, so I will tell you how I fixed this issue on a computer connected to wifi.

How to fix:

1) Click on the wifi icon in the taskbar, it will open the window with wifi connections

[image]

2) The network highlighted in purple is mine. Next click on properties. It will take you to this window:
[image]

mine is set to "Private", because I have already reset it, but yours is set to public and that is why your smartscreen can't be reached, because it doesn't use untrustworthy public networks and only works with private networks. Reset to private and your smartscreen will work again.

Do not just set any network to private, because you can compromise the security of your computer. Choose only the one you trust.

Comment: I just set up a fresh install, and my Wi-Fi network was set to Private from the outset, yet this issue occurs. So there's clearly a different cause here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the command prompt as admin and running.

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
```

I usually have this problem if airplane mode or Bluetooth was turned on for awhile then turned back off.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, You may turned off SmartScreen feature in settings. Open `Windows Defender Security Center` > `App and browser control`. Here check that the SmartScreen settings are set to their defaults:

Check apps and files: Warn
SmartScreen for Microsoft Edge: Warn
SmartScreen for Windows Store apps: Warn

Answer (score -1):

they changed it into a setting called "App & browser control"
search in settings and you will find it