# SmartSreen can't be reached in windows-10

Tags: windows-10

I've been trying to download Minecraft but it said "SmartScreen can't be reached."
I've tried everything I know, I can't download anything at all.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/980624/windows-smart-screen-cant-be-reached-in-windows-10

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description, I hope one of the following methods will be helpful to you.

1. Reboot your machine multiple times.
2. Install [latest Windows Updates](https://www.kapilarya.com/install-a-specific-windows-update-in-windows-10) available to you.
3. Make sure [virus and spyware definitions](https://www.kapilarya.com/virus-and-spyware-definitions-couldnt-be-updated-in-windows-defender) are up-to-date in [Windows Defender](https://www.kapilarya.com/this-app-is-turned-off-by-group-policy-windows-defender) and it is running.
4. Run [SFC scan](https://www.kapilarya.com/how-to-use-system-file-checker-to-repair-windows-10) and [DISM commands](https://www.kapilarya.com/fix-do-inbox-corruption-repair-using-dism-in-windows-8) to fix file corruption on machine.
5. Check if your Internet connection is working properly. It should be stable and have decent speed. You can run [Network Adapter troubleshooter](https://www.kapilarya.com/how-to-use-built-in-troubleshooters-in-windows-10) to look any problems with Internet connectivity and automatically fix them.
6. [Reset Internet Explorer](https://www.kapilarya.com/how-to-reset-internet-explorer) and [Microsoft Edge](https://www.kapilarya.com/how-to-completely-reset-microsoft-edge-to-default-settings) to defaults.
7. Delete temporary files stored on your Windows using steps mentioned [here](https://www.kapilarya.com/how-to-delete-temporary-files-in-windows-10).
8. In case if you’re using any third-party antivirus program, remove it and see if it helps.
9. If you’re quite sure that program you’re trying to run is safe and you can trust the vendor, temporarily de-activate Windows SmartScreen filter using either of the methods mentioned [here](https://www.kapilarya.com/how-to-use-windows-smartscreen-in-windows-10).
10. If the problem continues for a long time, you may try consider [refreshing Windows 10](https://www.kapilarya.com/reinstall-windows-10-without-affecting-personal-files) (reinstall without affecting your data).